# com.android.volley.ClientError error when using Volley in a fragment

Tags: android, android-volley

I am having difficulty consuming an API in my android project using volley

This API returns and works perfectly when called using postman
[image: postman1]

[image: postman2]

Please advise me on how to consume an API from an android fragment

See the below error. I get

```
com.android.volley.ClientError
```

see my code below

private void volleyApiCall(final String theEmail, final String theToken) {

```
// creating a new variable for our request queue
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

// on below line we are calling a string
// request method to post the data to our API
// in this we are calling a post method.
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // inside on response method we are
        // hiding our progress bar
        // and setting data to edit text as empty


        // on below line we are displaying a success toast message.
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: INSIDE RESPONSE");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data added to API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            // on below line we are passing our response
            // to json object to extract data from it.
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: >>  SUCCESS SUCCESS");
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: jsonObject >> " + jsonObject);
            String status = (jsonObject.getString("status"));
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: status >> " + status);

            String output = (jsonObject.getString("output"));
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: output >> " + output);

            String message = (jsonObject.getString("message"));
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: message >> " + message);


            if (status.equals("1")) {
                String balance = fetchBalance(email, token);
                tvBalance.setText(balance);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Unable to check wallet. Please Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            // on below line we are setting this string s to our text view.
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // method to handle errors.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to get response = " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: ERROR IS : >> "+ error.getMessage());
        Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: ERROR IS : >> "+ error.getStackTrace());
        Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: ERROR IS : >> "+ error.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: ERROR IS : >> "+ error);
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        // below line we are creating a map for
        // storing our values in key and value pair.
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", theEmail);
        params.put("token", theToken);

        // at last we are
        // returning our params.
        return params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");
        return params;
    }
};
request.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return 30000;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return 30000;
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

    }
});
// below line is to make
// a json object request.
queue.add(request);
}
```

-------EDITS -----
I added screenshot of the postman

Comment: try adding token to your header....also if you can add the postman success image with its params and header that will be very easy for us to help you

Comment: @unownsp, I edited the question to add  screenshots header in postman of postman

Comment: in your postman screenshot...check your response code....its 400 that is for bad request....ask your backend developer to make it 200 or 404...or it can be 401 for unauthorized access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, guys, the issue was the response code passed by my backend engineersOnce it was changed to 201 volley started picking up responses

Comment: I realised this as well. Kinda weird volley decided to go about the errors this way.